# Template deduction fails for polymorphic class with default template parameters

Tags: c++, polymorphism, default-parameters, template-argument-deduction

Consider this example:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class A {};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class B: public A<T1> {};

template<typename T = int>
void foo(std::shared_ptr< A<T> > test)
{

}

int main()
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<B<int, int>>();
    foo<int>(p);    // Works
    foo<>(p);       // Does not work
    foo(p);         // Does not work
}
```

I'm trying to get this to compile without explicitly specifying the type T for foo, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure why as if I explicitly the type T, it works just fine, but if I it, it doesn't compile, even though I've told the compiler the what the type T should be if I don't explicitly specify it.

I get why the compiler can't deduce the type T, but why can't it use my default type T when I don't specify it? How do I get around this and what is the "proper" way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't related to the default template parameter. Instead, the type of `p` (`std::shared_ptr<B<int, int>>`) can't be matched against the `std::shared_ptr<T>` argument of the template `foo`: During template argument deduction, no conversions are taken into account, and passing a reference to a derived class instance as a base class reference is indeed a conversion.

You can fix the issue by explicitly upcasting the pointer that `std::shared_ptr` manages.

```
std::shared_ptr<A<int>> p = std::make_shared<B<int, int>>();
```

Now, these calls will work out as expected:

```
foo<>(p); // Ok, argument matches the signature
foo(p);   // Same...
```

Note that it makes a big difference whether the template argument type appears in the parameter list of a function template (making deduction possible) or not. Consider these two templates,

```
template <class T = int> void foo(T&&)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

template <class T = int> void bar(double)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}
```

Both have the default type `int`, but when they are instantiated like this

```
foo<>(0.0); // outputs: void foo(T&&) [with T = double]
bar<>(0.0); // outputs: void bar(double) [with T = int]
```

the first instantiation uses the function argument to deduce the template parameter (results in `double`), while the second doesn't deduce anything and defaults to `int`.

Comment: So let me see if I get this right.
First the compiler tries to pick an overload by matching the types against the signature of the template functions. Which fails because B doesn't match A.
Then it creates signatures from all functions that matches, and does conversions as necessary to find the "best" overload.
And finally it instantiates the template. By explicitly specifying the template argument, we skip phase 1 and go directly to phase 2? If that is the case, then why doesn't the compiler consider the default argument for T when I use the <> syntax?

Comment: By explicitly instantiating `foo<int>(p)` you circumvent the whole template argument deduction. It is as you just added a function to the overload set named `foo`. Then, implicit conversion can happen during overload resolution, and as there is only one item in the set, `foo<int>` is chosen. With template argument deduction, the compiler never reaches overload resolution - as `foo`'s signature is unmatched, the overload set is empty. Hope that makes it a bit clearer?

Comment: Yes, it makes it clearer, why I'm still wonder why foo<>(p) doesn't work? Why is it not the same as foo<int>(p)? The reason I left the default type for T is that so I could explicitly instantiate the template without specifying the type T.

Comment: Got it. But still, the question remains if there's some clever way around this. The only options I see is explicitly specifying the type in some way (which I want to avoid), or make another overload that hardcodes the type T. Would be nice if one could merge these two overloads.